# How do I make my Python program check and wait for a txt file to be accessible?

Tags: python, wait

**Problem**
I have third-party software that generates a text file and appends a new line to it after x seconds.

My program reads the data points live from the text file and displays values as a plot in Matplotlib with FuncAnimation. However, sometimes it slows down because the software and Python obviously try to access the text file simultaneously when their timing overlaps.

**My Goal**
I want the Python code, when started at any point in time, to check if the text file is currently being used and if so, wait until it is not anymore. That means I want it to only try to access the file when it is actually not used by the software.

I appreciate your help!
(I do not think it is necessary to present a code example here because this is a more general question and not a specific problem in my code. Of course, I will do so if explicitly wished for!)

Comment: Does the software happen to acquire a lock on the file? That'd help…

Comment: @deceze I do not know right now, but does it help if you know that I get the message "Error Permission Denied ...", but ofc it keeps going if it is accessible again. The error just slows down the "re-start" of the curve plotting.

Comment: What OS are you using? You basically want to try to imitate the UNIX `tail -f ...` command (watching a file and always outputting its latest value)…?

Comment: @Nrmn this could also mean your 3rd.party software gets the same error if it tries to write when you puthon script is reding the file. Depending on its behavior, it could (worst to best) crash, never output that data point, or buffer that data point and write it on the next attempt.

Comment: @deceze Windows platform. I honestly do not know much more information, I am not a programmer :-p

Comment: @blarg The software works without any problems. It has priority. I do not have a real 'problem' in general until now, because it works, but instead of waiting for the file to be closed it would be nicer to synchronize the process ... :)